# Android Studio - Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8601): java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, usb, port

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 on Linux Mint 17.2. When I try to debug my app using a device connected to a usb port I get this error:

```
Error running app: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8601): java.net.NoRouteToHostException
```

I already try :

```
fuser -k 8601/tcp
```

I also updated SDK Build Tools.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Somehow, the problem was in my internet connection.
I use fixed IP, but I was connected using another IP due to a change in the router settings.
I don't know how it affects the Android Studio debugger, but this was my problem.